# assign value in else block of list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, conditional-operator

i want to refer two list and generate an output list by comparison.

```
occupied = [8,9,10]
broken = [1,2,3]

output = ['occupied' if x in occupied else x in broken for x in range(1,11)]
desired_output = ['broken', 'broken', 'broken', 'broken', False, False, False, 'occupied', 'occupied', 'occupied']
```

is it possible to achieve above in one pass?

currently i am doing two iteration

```
['broken' if x2==True else x2 for x2 in ['occupied' if x in occupied else x in broken for x in range(1,11)] ]
```

i was looking for something like this

```
['occupied' if x in occupied else 'broken' if x in broken for x in range(1,11)]
```

but this is incorrect syntax

Comment: 4 should be `False`, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it, just add an `else` clause to your solution (second `if` expression):

```
output = ["broken" if x in broken else 'occupied' if x in occupied else False for x in range(1,11)]
# Out[5]: ['broken', 'broken', 'broken', False, False, False, False, 'occupied', 'occupied', 'occupied']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this should work for you

```
occupied = [8,9,10]
broken = [1,2,3]
["occupied" if x in occupied else "broken" if x in broken else False for x in range(1,11)]
```

output:

```
['broken',
 'broken',
 'broken',
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 'occupied',
 'occupied',
 'occupied']
```